# Scoped style v-data- not applied on all elements

Tags: css, vuejs2

I'm using scoped styles on some of my components.
Style classes are so rendered with a [data-v-hash] and html elements get the [data-v-hash] attribute... but not all of them... why?

Let's take this navbar bootstrap4 navbar

```
    <template>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-light fixed-top navbar-expand-lg">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Home</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Menu
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">item1</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">item2</a>
        </div>
      </li>

    </ul>

  </div>
</nav>

</template>
```

then i use a custom scoped css which has for example among others

```
.navbar-brand{
    text-shadow: none;
    color: #737373;
    font-size:16px;
}
```

when rendered the style becomes

```
.navbar-brand[data-v-9fbb962c]{
    text-shadow: none;
    color: #737373;
    font-size:16px;
}
```

but the HTML is still

```
<a href="/admin" class="navbar-brand">Home</a>
```

while other elements correctly get the data-v attribute

Comment: I don't see the `a` element in your template. If the `a` is added by bootstrap then Vue can't add the data-v-xx attribute.

Comment: thanks, i edited th question removing BootstrapVue but problem still exists